# How to Check a Site is UP or not

Tags: php

I am using Php and i have to redirect customer to another site but need to check either that site is live or not, It should keep trying to reach that site for 30 second if site is not live and even after 30 second response is negative then it should show customer that service is down.

What should I do in this case. And also that site is not in my control and it is on jsp.

Comment: Please show us your research results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this function:

```
function ping($host,$port=80,$timeout=6)
{
    $fsock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if ( ! $fsock )
    {
            return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
            return TRUE;
    }
}
```

You can find more in this link: http://www.thecave.info/php-ping-script-to-check-remote-server-or-website/